# How to calculate average number of descendants?

Tags: statistics

Suppose $A_{n}$ denotes the set of all humans alive at the beginning of the year $n$. Therefore $A_{2018}$ has about 7.4 billion members, while $A_{0}$ has, let's assume, 200 million members. A person $x$ in the set $A_{0}$ has $k_x$ descendants in $A_{2018}$.

If we want to calculate the average $k$, i.e. the average number of descendants that a member from $A_{0}$ has in $A_{2018}$, what data are needed and what assumptions should be made? How to estimate the order of this number?

Note: There are tens of millions of people who claim to be Sayyid (descendant of Muhammad) while the status of being a Sayyid can only be attributed through the patrilineal lineage. I posted a question about the population of Sayyids [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/tens-of-millions-of-sayyids-is-it-possible).

Comment: I could also ask this in genealogy SE, but I thought math guys could find it easier?

Comment: Just perform a division

Comment: This is not a math question.  If you assume that all the $k_x$ are equal  then $k_x\approx 37$ for all $x$.  But...maybe that assumption is wrong.  Maybe one of the original ancestors has a vastly more powerful (i.e. numerous) line than the others.  Presumably that would be the argument against the $37$ and it is mathematically possible.

Comment: You can have $1000$ or more ancestors in $A_0$. The average $k$ is probably in order of millions.

Answer (score 1):

The average is
$$
\frac{\sum_{x \in A_0} k_x}{|A_0|}.
$$
But if you have access to the numbers $k_x$, then it seems your question is much more easily answered by the number $k_{\mathrm{Muhammad}}$.

Comment: The problem is, how to gain access to $k_x$. We have a complicated tree of generations, for which we need to make some assumptions.

Comment: Well, yeah. How many assumptions do you want to make? If you assume the simplest model -- where the population mixes perfectly -- you'll find that almost everyone is a descendant of any fixed person. Roughly speaking the percentage of the population that is their descendant will double every generation while that percentage is small, and as soon as the percentage of people that's *not* a descendant is small, *that* percentage will be roughly halving every generation. And 2018 is a very large number for an exponent.

Comment: Of course we know that societies don't mix very well at all, but you should expect that realistic estimates on the actual behavior of that are extremely hard.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out how fast (according to the "stupid" model) a given ancestor will have more descendants than there are people. I.e assuming 2 children per generation(extremely conservative for most of history), 20 year long generation and no interbreeding, you get over 8bill. descendants in only 660 years much less than the 2018 expected. In other words assuming even fairly small mixing you might get a very surprising number of descendants after 2000 years.